# C# Path.GetTempPath returns "Could not find a part of the path" error

Tags: c#

I am downloading a file from an ftp server and saving it to the directory defined in Path.GetTempPath(); however, I'm getting the following error: Could not find a part of the path.

I've confirmed that the path returned is correct: C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp.

SYSTEM, Administrators, and [username] all have full control over that directory. I thought the point of the temp directory was that it was open for anything/everyone to save to, but just in case, I gave NETWORK SERVICE Modify permissions as well. (I assume that's the username ASP.NET Dev server uses, but I'm not sure.)

I'm using VS 08 on Vista.

Here's my code:

```
FtpWebRequest downloadRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPServer"] + "//" + fileName);

downloadRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUsername"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPPassword"]);

downloadRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

FtpWebResponse downloadResponse = 
    (FtpWebResponse)downloadRequest.GetResponse();

try
{
    Stream downloadStream = downloadResponse.GetResponseStream();

    if (downloadStream != null) 
    {
        logger.Info("File Download status: {0}", 
            downloadResponse.StatusDescription);

        StreamReader downloadReader = new StreamReader(downloadStream);

        try
        {
            if (downloadReader != null)
            {

                StreamWriter downloadWriter = 
                    new StreamWriter(Path.GetTempPath());
                downloadWriter.AutoFlush = true;
                downloadWriter.Write(downloadReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (downloadReader != null)
            {
                downloadReader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    if (downloadResponse != null)
    {
        downloadResponse.Close();
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate any ideas about what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to add a file name to the end of the temp path.  Try this:

```
StreamWriter downloadWriter =
    new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName));
```

Comment: Thanks!!

I'm getting errors saying that my path has illegal characters when I use the code above but not when I hard-code the fileName, which is weird.

Comment: Double check the value of the string in fileName.  Maybe it needs to be sanitized of weird characters?

Comment: Yeah, checked that. I'm writing the string to the log, and it looks good: 2009-09-10124317Z_FirstLast_metadata.txt. And if I hardcode the string I copied from the log into the StreamWriter it works.

Comment: Just to follow up w/this, I needed to add Trim() to the fileName and couldn't tell from the log b/c I couldn't see the extra /r and /n characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
StreamWriter downloadWriter = 
                    new StreamWriter(Path.GetTempPath());
```

You're trying to open the StreamWriter on a directory rather than on a file.  If you want a temp filename, use [`Path.GetTempFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) instead:

```
StreamWriter downloadWriter = 
                    new StreamWriter(Path.GetTempFileName());
```

Either that or do what Skinniest Man said.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but it gives the file a .tmp extension. Is there a way to preserve the file extension?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like CreateTempFileName doesn't have any overrides.  You could do something with Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName, and Path.ChangeExtension to get the file you want, though.  However, you might want to just write the filename unchanged rather than doing all this, which is what Skinniest Man's code does.